# When do group-invariant bivariate functions depend on the distance only?

Tags: lie-groups, harmonic-analysis, symmetry

Let $M$ denote the sphere $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ and let $G$ denote the group $O(d)$ of orthogonal $d\times d$ matrices. Suppose that the function
$$
F\colon M\times M\to \mathbb R
$$
is $G$-invariant, in the sense that
$$
F(R\omega, R\nu)=F(\omega, \nu), \qquad \forall \omega, \nu\in\mathbb S^{d-1}, \forall R\in G.$$
Then there is a $\phi\colon [-1, 1]\to \mathbb R$ such that
$$
F(\omega, \nu)=\phi(\omega\cdot \nu).$$
In other words, $F$ depends only on the distance of its arguments. (See below for the proof).

---

Now redo the above reasoning with $M=\mathbb R^d$ and $G=(\mathbb R^d, +)$. A function $F$ is now $G$-invariant if
$$
F(x-z, y-z)=F(x, y), \qquad \forall x, y\in M,\ \forall z\in G.$$
The inference that can be drawn from this is that
$$
F(x, y)=\psi(x-y), \quad \text{ for a }\psi\colon \mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R, $$
which is weaker than before; the function now depends on the *difference* $x-y$, not on the *distance* $|x-y|$.

> **Question**. Can you give a conceptual explanation of this different behavior?

---

I purposely wrote a vague question, because I would love to receive insight of any kind. However, I do have a framework in mind. In both examples above,
$$
M=G/K, \quad \text{ where } G\text{ is a Lie group, }$$
and $K$ is the stabilizer of an arbitrarily chosen point of $M$. Moreover, $M$ is a $G$-invariant Riemannian manifold.

Now there are two major differences between the two cases. On the sphere, $G=O(d)$ is compact, and the stabilizer $K$ is isomorphic to $O(d-1)$. Both properties fail on $\mathbb R^d$, for which $K=\{0\}$ is the trivial subgroup.

I have this vague idea that the different behavior is a consequence of these two different properties.

---

Proof of the statement on the sphere.

Without loss of generality we can assume that $\omega$ is the North Pole $e_d\in\mathbb S^{d-1}$. We can write $\nu\in\mathbb S^{d-1}$ in cylindrical coordinates
$$
\nu= t e_d + \sqrt{1-t^2}\nu_{d-2}, $$
where $t=e_d\cdot \nu$ and $ \nu_{d-2}\in\mathbb S^{d-2}$. Thus, obviously,
$$
F(e_d, \nu)=F(e_d, te_d + \sqrt{1-t^2}\nu_{d-2}).$$
So $F$ is a function of the two variables $t, \nu_{d-2}$. However, for each rotation $R\in O(d)$ such that $Re_d=e_d$ we have that
$$
F(e_d, \nu)=F(e_d, R\nu)=F(e_d, te_d + \sqrt{1-t^2}R\nu_{d-2}).$$
This shows that, actually, $F$ does not depend on $\nu_{d-2}$ and is therefore a function of $t$ only. $\Box$

Comment: The first claim is simply wrong once $d\ge 3$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: do you mean the sphere case? I respectfully disagree with you. The fact that F depends only the distance is independent on the dimension. Essentially, we assume that one of the arguments is the North Pole and write the other in cylindrical coordinates, and it becomes clear that the resulting function depends on only one variable. I am writing from a mobile phone and it is difficult for me to enter formulas, but I will add a proof later.

Comment: Oh, sorry, for some reason I was thinking about invariant kernels on $G$ instead of $G/H=S^{d-1}$. Yes, the explanation is different degree of transitivity for the action: $G$ acts on itself via left multiplication simply transitively. This is what happens when you consider $G=M=R^d$ and the quotient of $G\times G$ by the left action of $G$ is naturally $G$. But in the sphere example you have the quotient of $G/H \times G/H$ by the left action of $G$ and I think you get the biquotient $H\backslash G/H$, which is much smaller.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: this is a great insight, thanks.

Comment: You might be interested to learn about "two point homogeneous spaces"

Comment: @Max: thanks, that gives a very simple explanation of the observed phenomenon. Both $\mathbb S^{d-1}$ and $\mathbb R^{d}$ are 2-point homogeneous under their respective isometry groups, but I have to consider the FULL isometry group. For the sphere, it is $O(d)$. But for $\mathbb R^{d}$ the isometry group is bigger than $(\mathbb R^d,+)$, I should include rotations and reflections. If I included those, I would have gotten the exact same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my comments:

Suppose that $G$ is a locally compact topological group (I am primarily thinking about Lie groups, but this is also used for other locally compact groups, such that p-adic groups), $H< G$ is a closed subgroup. The group $G$ acts (continuously) diagonally via left multiplication on $G\times G$ and, hence, on the product of quotient-spaces $Z=G/H\times G/H$. Let's analyze the quotient $Q$ of $Z$ by this $G$-action: One can regard $Q$ as the "parameter space" parameterizing the $G$-congruence classes of pairs $(p, q)\in Z$.

We can first take the quotient of $G\times G$ by the (left) $G$-action. This quotient is homeomorphic to $G$ and the homeomorphism is induced by the map
$$
\nu: (g, h)\mapsto g^{-1} h, G\times G\to G. 
$$
The point is that for each $f\in G$, $\nu(f(g,h))= \nu((fg, fh))$. Under this  identification of the quotient of $G\times G$, the right $H\times H$-action on $G\times G$ becomes
$$
(h_1,h_2) g= h_1^{-1}gh_2. 
$$
Hence, $G\backslash (G/H \times G/H)$ is homeomorphic to the biquotient $H\backslash G/H$. Note that the nonebelian nature of $G$ (if it is nonabelian) becomes important here: If $H$ were normal in $G$, then  $H\backslash G/H$ would be homeomorphic to $G/H$.

Now, depending on $G$ and $H$ the space $Q$ might be 1-dimensional or higher dimensional. The examples I am most familiar with (besides the ones in the post) are:

Symmetric spaces of noncompact type $X=G/H$ where $G$ is a semisimple connected Lie group and $H=K$ is its maximal compact subgroup. The biquotient $Q=H\backslash G/H$ is then described by the Cartan decomposition of $G$:
$$
G= K A_+ K
$$
and $A_+$ is homeomorphic (via the exponential map) to a positive chamber ${\mathfrak a}_+$ in the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak a}$ of $A$. Thus, $Q$ is homeomorphic to $A_+$. The dimension of $Q$ is also known as *rank* of the symmetric space $X$. The space $X$ has rank 1 precisely when the $G$-congruence classes of pairs of points $(p,q)$ in $X$ are parameterized by the metric distance $d(p,q)$. One of the standard examples of the Cartan decomposition is the SVD (singular value decomposition) of $G=SL(n, {\mathbb R})$, $K=SO(n)$ and $A$ is the subgroup of diagonal matrices in $G$. Once $n\ge 3$, you have more than one independent singular value (if $n=2$ then the singular values are inverses of each other and, effectively, you just need one of them).

A similar story is for $p$-adic groups such as $G=SL(n, {\mathbb Q}_p)$: in this case Cartan decomposition is known as the  *Smith Normal Form* of a matrix.  The analogue of $K$ in this setting is $K=SL(n, \widehat{\mathbb Z}_p)$, where $\widehat{\mathbb Z}_p$ is the ring of p-adic integers. (As a topologist, I do not like the notation  ${\mathbb Z}_p$ for this ring, but I am biased.)

People study algebras of biinvariant functions on biquotients $Q=H\backslash G/H$ in these examples (both Lie algebras and p-adic cases); the product on these algebras is given by the convolution. (The fact that the product is commutative is a bit surprising, I think, this observation is due to Gelfand.) These algebras are known as Hecke algebras/rings. The biinvariant functions on $G$ are called [spherical functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem_for_spherical_functions#Spherical_functions). In other words (coming back to your post), these are $G$-invariant functions on $G/H \times G/H$.

Comment: This is extremely interesting. Thanks. Just an introductory question, what is the difference between the quotient denoted with $/$ and the one denoted with $\backslash$?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: This notation distinguishes quotient taken when a group acts via left or right multiplication. For instance, $G/H$ is the set of cosets $gH, g\in G$, while $H\backslash G$ denotes the set of cosets $Hg$.